# How To Concat in List - Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, concatenation

I have list in Js :

```
$("div#boxCartList input[class='inputPrdNo']").each(function(index){
var listPrdNo = $(this).val(); )};
```

listPrdNo is the list of many prdNo (ex : 2334 7782 9923 2323 2324 4342 dst)

I want to select only 3 top prdNo and using "," (prdNo , prdNo , prdNo)

i tried to concat like this

```
            var limit = listPrdNo.length < 3 ? listPrdNo.length : 3;
            if (listPrdNo.length > 1){
            for(var i =0; i < limit; i++){
            var prdNum  = $("div#boxCartList input[class='inputPrdNo']")[i];
            if (i == 0){
            p += prdNum;
            }
            if (i > 0 && i < limit ){
            p += ",";
            }
            if (i > 0){
            p += prdNum;
            }
            }}else if (listPrdNo.length == 1){
             var prdNum = $("div#boxCartList input[class='inputPrdNo']")[0];
             p += prdNum;
            }
```

but the result is undefined , can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you give the HTML please?

Comment: The issue is your first posted line of code, it's iterating over your inputs, ie the function is running once for every input, it isn't giving you the list. Use something like var products = $(selectors).slice(0, 3).map( <here return the value from the input> );

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler way to do this if I understand you correctly:

```js
var listPrdNo = [];

$("div#boxCartList input[class='inputPrdNo']").each(function(index){ listPrdNo.push( $(this).val() ); ) };

var limit = listPrdNo.length < 3 ? listPrdNo.length : 3;

var top3 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    top3.push(listPrdNo[i]);
}
var result = top3.join(" , ");

console.log(result); // Now you can use the result string however you want!
```

Comment: @fmou no problem, if it works then don't forget to upvote/accept the question! ;D